# Changing keystroke access priority in Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, keyboard

When one input a keystroke (or a combination of keystrokes) on Microsoft Windows, the keystroke is sent to one or several programs, sequentially. For example, the keystroke may be first sent to Windows (e.g., entering  <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> opens Windows Explorer), then to the program that has the focus.

I'm looking for a program for Microsoft Windows 7 or 10 that can change the order in which the keystroke is sent to the running programs.

Any license or price is fine.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Del is a bad example as this key combination is always handled by Windows itself for security reasons. Sounds to me like an XY problem. You should post your actual problem and what you want to achieve at superuser.com.

Comment: @Robert my actual pb is change the order in which the keystroke is sent to the running programs. It'd be handy in several programs eg VMs or VNCs.

Comment: As I said Ctr+Alt+Del is hard-coded to be sent directly to the host Windows system.

Comment: @Robert As I said Ctr+Alt+Del is  just an example.

Comment: As I said it is the worst example you could select. Reconsider it and change it to something more reasonable. However I am not sure if the key management part of Windows is configurable. As far as I remember you can write hooks for getting the key pressings yourself but if I remember correctly this allows you only to "consume" the key pressings and thus prevent other apps from receiving it but the order in which apps are notified is up to WIndows.

Comment: @Robert thanks, I changed the example.